# In Polymer, how to manipulate local DOM programmatically (e.g. like dom-repeat)

Tags: polymer

I would like to be manipulate the local DOM programmatically (i.e. using JavaScript code). I would like to achieve a functionality somehow similar to what dom-repeat does.

Some pseudo-code:

```
<dom-module id="my-grid">
<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-grid',
    ready: function() {
       for each item in dataProvider {
          var childInstance = INSTANTIATE renderer (from shadow dom)
          localDOM.addChild(childInstance);
       }
    }
  });
```

The practical use case for this: I want to have a grid component (e.g. 3 rows x 3 cols), that repeats the children. I tried to look at the core-list implementation from 0.5, but I didn't understand the mechanics very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered how to do it. Something like:

```
setRenderer: function(renderer) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var inst = document.createElement(renderer);
        inst.owner = i;
        Polymer.dom(this.root).appendChild(inst);
    }
}
```